# URP Lit Shader breaks Static Batching

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, batching, urp

I'm using Static Batching to reduce Draw Calls, having the same material for the most part of the meshes rendered in the scene. I've also set the Static flag to true in all of these GameObjects, and so on the Static flag in the Player Settings. In that unique material, I'm using de URP lit shader, and this is causing that Batched Draw Calls of Static Batching are 0 (zero), but if I change the material's shader to Unlit/Texture (for example) this number increases to 40 or more (you can see it in the attached pictures).

My question is: is there any way to use the URP lit shader without breaking the Static Batching or any other solution that keeps my graphics working with Static Batching?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: this is an app for mobile devices.

With URP lit shader:

[image: With URP lit shader]

With default unlit shader:

[image: With default unlit shader]